# Retrofit 1.9 keeps calling failure and returns null body

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, retrofit

I am trying to communicate with my php web service (Google App Engine), but it keeps responding with body as null and also triggering the failure() method of Retrofit (callback).

I get the following error message in failure(), when debugging it:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

First here is the code where I trigger the request to my web service:

```
 WebServiceManager.getInstance().registerRequest(email, password, username, firstname, lastname, new Callback<RegisterResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(RegisterResponse registerResponse, Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, registerResponse.getToken() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(context,"error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

And here is my WebServiceManager class for managing the requests and responses:
http://pastebin.com/Q8bzqQ0M

And the model classes for the requests and responses:
http://pastebin.com/aB98Yiua

This is how my json request looks like:

```
{
    data{
        "email": "regd@rgersf.dk",
        "firstname": "regdrgersf",
        "lastname": "regdrgersf",
        "password": "hejhejhej",
        "username": "regdrgersf"
    }
}
```

I also think it is relevant to include the part where I receive the request on my web service:

```
<?php
require '../functions/db.php';

$data = getJsonRequest();

$email      = $data['data']['email'];
$password   = $data['data']['password'];
$username   = $data['data']['username'];
$firstname  = $data['data']['firstname'];
$lastname   = $data['data']['lastname'];
$facebookID = $data['data']['facebookID'];

$dbClass = new DBClass();
$result = $dbClass->register($email, $password, $username, $firstname, $lastname, $facebookID);

$response = array();
if ($result == $dbClass->error_input || $result == $dbClass->error_email_exists || $result == $dbClass->error_unknown || $result == $dbClass->error_db_connection) {
    $response['status'] = false;
    $response['error'] = $result;

} else {
    $response['status'] = true;
    $response['token'] = $result;
}

sendJsonResponse($response);

?>
```

And the function "sendJsonResponse($response)" for sending the response:

```
function sendJsonResponse($response) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I can't figure out if the problem is somewhere in my Java (Android) code and retrofit or if I'm doing something wrong on the webserver.

Comment: There's a problem with your json but I don't see where you're setting that up.

Comment: The exception is pretty descriptive, Retrofit was expecting a JSON object like {"key":"value"}, but the response was a simple String.. You can debug the response with .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) on your RestAdapter.Builder()

Comment: Can you post the JSON that your PHP is outputting?

Comment: @nasch I am setting it up in the code provided with the pastebin link in my question. it is the method registerRequest(...)

Comment: @luciofm I am setting the log level to .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL), which can be seen in the pastebin link provide in the question.. but I don't know if I am doing it in a wrong though

Comment: @user Your pastebin link doesn't include the `RegisterRequest` and `RegisterResponse` classes which are causing the error.

Comment: @Brucelet yes of course. you are right. I will provide another link at once. sorry about that :)

Comment: @user68621 you need to provide the response from the webserver...

Comment: @luciofm I can't seem to get the full response from my java code, other than with debugging where I can see that I get a 200 OK header and body is null. But if I run i through Postman I does what it is supposed to. I think the problem is related to the request (at least), because the purpose of the request, is to register a user and nothing is added to the database when I send the request from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix it myself, so I think I should post my solution here so that it might help others.. even though I am not sure why my first solution didn't work. 
By removing the annotation @FormUrlEncoded and changing @Field('data') to @Body, it actually worked. Så the interface looks like this now.

```
private interface webServiceInterface {
    @POST(WebServiceManager.REQUEST_REGISTER)
    void register(@Body RegisterRequest registerRequest, Callback<RegisterResponse> response);
}
```

Anyways, I really appreciate all the help I got from people here.